# Customizing the appearance of UITableViewCell during editing

Tags: ios, tableview, editing

How do I customize the appearance of a UITableViewCell when the tableView is given the edit call.

I need to hide some objects, and reveal a couple buttons on edit. And move things around a little bit. What is the delegate method I should pay attention to?

I want to change the appearance of all cells like when apple does it when there's an accessory delete button on the left? I need to do it before I select any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up customizing the appearance of my UITableViewCell subclass in the method. This method is called inside the cell (in TableViewCellCustom.m)

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would want to listen to tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex: and tell your view that it's selected.

that being said, you will have to subclass UIView and do your customizing in there and then add it to a UITableViewCells contentView.

That is what I would do.

Comment: what about changing the appearance of all cells like when apple does it when there' an accessory delete button on the left? I need to do it before I select any rows

Comment: Again, you need to create a custom view for this. try to look up some uitableview programming.

Comment: I have a subcalssed uitableview cell. is that what you mean?

Comment: You can do either. I prefer to add a UIView (custom subclass) to the standard UITableViewCell's contentView property. But you can also animate and add gestures to a subclass of UITableViewCell.